# What's this Colour?

Tags: part-identification, colour

Blue on the left, unknown in the middle, dark turquoise on the right.

It's got a slightly greener tint than dark blue. Do you know if they change the color over time? It's like this on the entire brick, so I assume it's not faded.

I've tried every possible color on Bricklink and a couple color guides, I'm lost.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The color of the 2x4 plate and 1x2 jumpers in the photo appears to be regular Dark Blue:

[image]

The greenish tint you mention is likely discoloration.  Here is an example of a discolored regular blue piece (right) next to a fairly new regular blue piece (left) for comparison:

[image]

How uniform or consistent the discoloraton is depends on the cause and/or whether the piece was assembled when it occurred.

Comment: I should have included that for comparison, but unfortunately its not.
Its got a slightly greener tint than dark blue. Do you know if they change the color over time? Its like this on the entire brick, so I assume its not faded.

Comment: @Zach Turley - Based on my experience, blues brick of all shades can turn a dingy greenish color with age, sunlight or excessive heat. The shade of green, of course, depends on the shade of blue.  I have just recently treated some discolored dark blue bricks (among many others) with hydrogen peroxide, heat and a fluorescent light with very good results.  There are a variety of methods using hydrogen peroxide to restore plastic color. A quick Google search will help you find instructions if you're interested.

Comment: Greenish accent on blue bricks appear due to so called "yellowing" process. It happens a lot with older bricks. So they get more of yellow/brown tint over time. I do believe the color you are looking at is Dark Blue [BL]. It is just bricks got yellowed.

Comment: @JohnnyB Thank you for the update and great answer.  I didn't realize that heat/age would be another factor instead of just sunlight: the bottoms are identical in color to the top, so I believed discoloration was not the case here.